# Include JS class in an Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to include the JavaScript code below to my Angular app (got this one from our designer team).

Before:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
window.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
});
window.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
  body.classList.add('-scroll');
});
window.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
  body.classList.remove('-scroll');
});
```

What I've tried - is to add a Scroll class for it, like in the code below. As a result - I have no errors, but also no result; probably the code is wrong. Can you please tell me how to fix it, or maybe offer a better solution for this.

After (not working):

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    new Scroll().init();
  }, 100);
}

export class Scroll {
  body: any;

  init() {
    this.body = document.querySelector('body');

    window.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {});
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
      this.body.classList.add('-scroll');
    });
    window.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
  this.body.classList.remove('-scroll');
    });
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use angular `HostListener` decorator see [usage](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener#usage-notes)

```
export class Scroll {

  @HostListener('window:touchstart', ['$event'])
  onWindowTouchstart($event) {
    // your code
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, still not working as expected, but I will keep trying.. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew could you please tell me how did you tested the touch event ?